# Multiplication and division operations of $0$ and $\infty$

Tags: infinity, nonstandard-analysis

> Note: This post can't be considered as a personal theory. These are the arguments which I figured out by reasoning and I just want to know it's validity.

Here I present multiplication and division operations of $0$ and $\infty$ by pure reasoning.
$$\dfrac{x}{0}=\infty$$
(where $0$ is positive infinitesimal)
$$AND$$
$$\dfrac{x}{0}=-\infty$$(where $0$ is negative infinitesimal)

If we divide $x$ by a small no., we get a big no.
$$\dfrac{x}{small}=big$$

If we keep on dividing $x$ by a small no. and then by another small no. and so on, we get bigger and bigger no.
$$\dfrac{x}{small\times small\times.....}=big\times big\times.....$$

Similarly if we divide $x$ by a negative small no. and then by another small no. and so on, we get bigger and bigger negative no.
$$\dfrac{x}{-small\times small\times.....}=-big\times big\times.....$$

However while doing this, two facts should be noted:

(1) The small no. in the denominator of LHS will never reach $0$.

(2) The big no. in the RHS will never reach $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Thus by reasoning, if we ever imagine that the small no. in the denominator of LHS is $0$ (which is impossible), we should also imagine that the positive or negative big no. in the RHS is $\infty$ or $-\infty$ respectively (which is also impossible). Is it a reasonable proof for "dividing a no. by zero, we get positive or negative infinity i.e. $\frac{x}{0}=\infty$ or $-\infty$"?

Now by algebraic manipulation,

$$0\times\infty=x$$(where $0$ is positive infinitesimal)
$$AND$$
$$0\times-\infty=x$$(where $0$ is negative infinitesimal)

But is algebraic manipulation legal here?

Here, two facts should be noted:

(1) We can never add zero infinite times in positive or negative no. line

(2) We can never get $x=$ non-zero when we keep adding zero over and over.

Thus by reasoning, if we ever imagine that we added zero infinite times (which is impossible), we should also imagine that $x=$ non-zero (which is also impossible). Is it a reasonable proof for "infinity times zero is non-zero i.e. $0\times\infty=x$"?

If it is true, then by algebraic manipulation of $0$ and $\infty$, we are getting logically correct answers.

---

Now we observe $0\times\infty=x$ could be any no. and hence is undefined. If we want to make $x$ a well defined no., we should make no. lines of $0$ and $\infty$ as an extension of real no. line and give several values for $0$ and $\infty$ like:

[image]
$$OR$$
[image]

Similarly:
[image]

Now if we choose particular values of $0$ and $\infty$, we get a well defined value of $x$. For example:

$$(0\times2)\times(\infty\times3)=(\infty^{-1}\times2)\times(\infty\times3)=2\times3\times\infty^{-1}\times\infty=6$$

---

Now can we consider this no. line of $0$ as the infinitesimal no. line of non-standard analysis?

In a similiar way, can we also define no. lines of *infinitesimal of infinitesimal* (second order differentials) and of *infinite of infinite* and so on?

[image]
[image]

Am I anywhere incorrect in my reasoning? Are my conclusions logically correct?

Comment: Do not threat $\infty$ as a number and do not divide by $0$. But for the sake of understanding how limits work, those approaches are not bad at all, but you shouldn't argue this way. In particular, $0\cdot\infty$ is not defined because the argument $\frac{x}{0}=\infty$ would hold for every positive real number $x$, if it was valid, so all numbers would be equal. In short, useful for memorization, but mathematically problematic.

Comment: What is your definition of $\infty$?

Comment: @Chappers: Infinity means unreachable (therefore not a number).

Comment: A definition is only useful if it helps to produce interesting results. How do your definition into the existing results? Analytical ones in particular? (As the motivation is mainly analytical).

Comment: There is a theory of infinitesimals (called [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)) which admits infinites ($\infty$ and its friends like $\infty +9$) and infinitesimals (for instance $\frac1{\infty}$). However, they do not allow division by zero, nor it holds $\frac{1}{\infty}$. In that context, it is not true that every number smaller than any positive rational is $\le0$. A little known theory of "[wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory)" has been proposed, which allows division by zero. However, most properties of operations do not hold.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: I meant "if we use only real number system, division by zero or infinity is undefined". However if we make additional no. lines, division by zero or infinity has a menaing????

Comment: +1 for your curiosity, I've added some videos in my answer that might interest you.

Comment: What if you approach 0 from the negative end?  E.g. $\frac{1}{-small}=-big$, so $\frac{1}{-reallysmall}=-reallybig$, so then $\frac{1}{0}=-\infty$. How would you deal with that?

Comment: @Bram28: In the language of extended coordinate system (i.e. zero coordinate system), $\infty^{-1}$ and $-\infty^{-1}$ are different (infinitesimal) quantities. So dividing something by each one of them yields different results. In real no. system, $\infty^{-1}$ and $-\infty^{-1}$ are the same, i.e. zero. So in the language of real coordinate system, division by zero is undefined. Hope I am not missing anything.

Comment: @Joe Well, what I meant was: You seemed to give an argument that $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$, but I could using that same logic to argue that $\frac{1}{0}=-\infty$ ... so it seems that there must be something wrong with the logic ...

Comment: I get it. It seems there is something missing in my argument. Let me edit it.

Comment: @Bram28: I have edited my post in the light of your argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations! You just re-invented [Abraham Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Robinson)'s [framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) for analysis with infinitesimals.  Note that denoting an infinitesimal by $0$ or more precisely by $o$ has a respectable history starting at least with Isaac Newton.  Furthermore, [Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) tended to refer to infinitesimals as "exactly zero".

Be that as it may, it turned out to be more productive to use a different notation for them, for example $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ for typical infinitesimals and $H$ and $K$ for typical infinite numbers; see Keisler's wonderful textbook [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) for details.

Other than that, the formalism you outlined is perfectly valid, and is much better received by the students than the traditional epsilon-delta approach; see [this recent study](http://dx.doi.org/10.5642/jhummath.201701.07).

Comment: I have sent you an e-mail regarding this. Please check.